# GWT-GXT 3.0 Graph

Tags: extjs, gwt, gxt, gwt2, gxt-charts

I am trying to populate the graph. i am planning to customize the graph.
i used below URL for constructing GRAPH.'

https://demo.borland.com/gxt-examples-3.0.1/index.html#ExamplePlace:linechart

1. I want to modify the y-axis based on the plotting value.
   EX :
   if value is starting from 50 to 100 means , then my y-axis should start from 50 (NOt from 0).
2. Modify the distance between x-axis value (Date).

   EX :
   i am having the plotting value from 7/10/2020 to 15/10/2020 and final value will be 25/10/2020

At present implementation , distance between x-axis value are equally distributed.but what i need is i want to display all the date between 7/10/2020 to 25/10/2020.

From **16/10/2020 to 24/10/2020** (we don't any data between this date)value in x-axis should not display(hidden) so that i can have the space between the date.

Answer (score 1):

1. NumericAxis supports `setMinimum` and `setMaximum` to control the first and last value that is visible on it. The default mode is to ensure that zero is visible, so once you take over the range, you'll also want to use `setSteps`/`setInterval` to manage the display of markers on the side.
2. To achieve this, you will need to define a function that takes the original dates, maps them to some other format such that all values between 16/10 and 24/10 are the same point, but data before and after that gap end up being evenly spread. Then, in order to have correct labeling, you will need a second function that maps back from this "gap" space to give good axis labels and tooltips.